# storage account -- export blob size and date

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Today I have a storage account with 500 blob containers and 30 million blobs

I need to get or export the modification date and size of each blob.

As a first measure I don't want to change anything to cold or archive. I just want to see with an export the date of each blob and its size

Any ideas to obtain this data?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all the blobs in a container you can use the following powershell command

```
Start-Transcript -path C:\output.txt -append
Get-AzureStorageContainer | Get-AzureStorageBlob
Stop-Transcript
```

The output from the command would include name and last modified date.

Comment: you don't have to supply a container name if you want them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to visually inspect the last modification date and size of your blobs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell command to list them.  You can play around with the output to make it cleaner but this will get you the data you requested.

```
$resourceGroupName="<RGName>"
$storageAccName="<STRAcctName>"

$storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName 

$ctx=$storageAcc.Context  

Get-AzStorageContainer  -Context $ctx  | Get-AzStorageBlob -IncludeDeleted
```